# Node: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: bash, path, npm

I installed Node and NPM with Homebrew. I then installed Susi:

```
npm install -g susi
/Users/oliver/.node/bin/susi -> /Users/oliver/.node/lib/node_modules/susi/susi
susi@0.2.3 /Users/oliver/.node/lib/node_modules/susi
├── hairlip@0.0.1
├── tiny-ssi@0.0.2
├── commonmark@0.12.0
└── moment@2.8.3
```

But trying to use Susi, I get the error:

```
-bash: susi: command not found
```

So, I edited .profile. echo $PATH returns this:

```
/Users/oliver/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/oliver/.node/lib/node_modules
```

Still, it can't be found. I assume I need to tell it to look in directories within /nodule_modules but I'm unsure how to go about it. Shouldn't NPM be managing this automatically? Is my $PATH set up correctly or have I missed something out?

(Sorry for having to ask about something so basic. Any help would be appreciated!)

EDIT:

I completely uninstalled Node and NPM following the instructions here: http://hungred.com/how-to/completely-removing-nodejs-npm/

This time I used NPM to install Jasmine (globally).

```
$ which jasmine
/usr/local/bin/jasmine

$ echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/local/bin
```

But when I try to use Jasmine:

```
$ node jasmine bob_test.spec.js
```

I get this error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/oliver/exercism/javascript/bob/jasmine'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Node seems to be looking for a local install only. I'm utterly confused...

EDIT:

I cloned a repo from github. Then:

```
$ npm install
```

All dependencies are installed to node_modules folder. However, running the code using node, I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'contra.emitter'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
...
```

Although contra.emitter is clearly installed in the node_modules folder. Have I missed something painfully obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
npm install -g npm
```

to update npm.

Try again to install `susi`.

Ideally, the `susi` gets setup in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Tried that. Still not working. It's now looking in my home directory!

Comment: ...looks like something's broken. I just cloned a project from GitHub. Node is unable to find the modules that I installed with NPM (to node_modules).